# How can i allocate a unique value to a column field in SQL Server, if no value is inserted?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

how can i  allocate a unique value to a column field in sql server, if no value is inserted? 
can i set some value on filed in sql server? i dont wan t to make it identity column, because some times records may be inserted from front end. But not always, in that case the column should automatically have a unique value which dont exist in the column already.

Answer (score 4):

You could use a Guid, and set default value for the column to `newid()`.

Comment: How can i use it in back end, having any idea?

Comment: If you are inserting data into a table from your application, you can omit the PK because it will be created automatically.

Answer (score 2):

A GUID is a good option. Specifically, you can read about COMBs, which are a kind of GUIDs that perform better than ordinary GUIDs.

And here is another thread that you may find useful:

[Performance value of COMB guids](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1155454/performance-value-of-comb-guids)

Answer (score 1):

You've got at least 3 options:

1. Make it an IDENTITY column, and use `SET IDENTITY_INSERT` ([see link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa259221%28v=sql.80%29.aspx)) to allow you to insert values when you have one.
2. Use a function to set the [default value](http://www.devx.com/tips/Tip/13703).
3. Use an "AFTER INSERT" trigger to update the field if it is null.

Comment: Sorry - I screwed up the link. See the link I've added. Basically, it's a way of allowing you to insert a specified value into an identity column.

Comment: No, it don't work, i already have a column set identity column. I need other solution.