# Which PK type to use Int or BigInt or UniqueIdentifier

Tags: sql-server

Our team developing a new database for health care ERP. During the brain storming meeting I recommended to use the `uniqueidentifier` because it has many benefits like

- Less round trip to the database `OnInsert` if we generate the value from client application
- By generating it on the client application, we can use more easily the master-detail approach.
- It helps in data replication

Till now, I was confident and even I thought I would hear some compliments, till my boss asked me couple of questions:

- You are going to use this `Guid` as primary key with clustered indexing? .
- Do you know the size of your table how big it and its consequences on the performance?
- Some of the developers proposed the `Int` and others `BigInt`

I would like to know if my Boss questions have a base or what I am thinking is true because what I think is best thing for building ERP with replication support.

**NOTE** I did already search for long time here in this site and on other sites also.

Which of the above is the best key to be used in ERP like health care information system?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9727090/unique-identifier-guid-as-primary-key-in-database-design

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11938044/what-are-the-best-practices-for-using-a-guid-as-a-primary-key-specifically-rega

Comment: Big disadvantage of guids as primary key is when clustered: each insert will cause, on average, 50% of rows to move. Hence the question about how big the table will be. I also find guids are a pain when manually querying (harder to spot the same value) and prefer `int` as being simpler.

Answer (score 1):

Think about what your company is proposing to do and the level of expertise your group currently has. Apparently it does not have significant experience with sql server based on your questions and your manager's questions. I cannot reasonably see a way for you to develop an enterprise-scale system without the necessary expertise - especially with the backend systems that you plan on using.

And your process (as little as you describe it) sounds concerning. "Brainstorming" is not, IMO, a point where you decide on schemas and choose keys. And one should not just blindly choose a particular datatype for **every primary key**. But all of this is guessing without knowing more about where you are in this process. If your schema is not yet fixed (regardless of what datatypes are selected for each column), then you are not yet in a position to worry about performance.

Lastly, you and your manager confuse two related but independent attributes. A primary key is not the same as the clustered index, despite the unfortunate implementation choices made by the MS development team. They are independent of each other; make a conscious decision about your clustered indexes and do not allow the db engine to automatically choose the primary key as the clustered index.

So to answer your questions. Yes - those questions are valid. But your project does not yet appear to have reached a point where those concerns can be addressed.