# Correct SQL to convert mySQL tables to SQL Server tables

Tags: sql-server

I have a number of tables I need to convert from mySQL to SQL Server.

An Example of a mySQL Table is

```
CREATE TABLE `required_items` (
`id` INT( 11 ) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY COMMENT 'Unique Barcode ID',
`fk_load_id` INT( 11 ) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Load ID', 
`barcode` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Barcode Value',
`description` VARCHAR( 255 ) NULL DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Barcode Description',
`created` TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Creation Timestamp',
`modified` TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP COMMENT 'Modified Timestamp',
FOREIGN KEY (`fk_load_id`) REFERENCES `loads`(`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE = InnoDB CHARACTER SET ascii COLLATE ascii_general_ci COMMENT = 'Contains Required Items for the Load';
```

And a trigger to update the created date

```
CREATE TRIGGER required_items_before_insert_created_date BEFORE INSERT ON `required_items`
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  SET NEW.created = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
END
```

Now I need to create tables similar to this in SQL Server.  There seems to be a lot of different data types available so I am unsure which to use.

- What data type should I use to the primary key column
  (uniqueidentifier, bigint, int)?
- What should I use for the timestamps
  (timestamp, datatime, datetime2(7))?
- How should I enforce the created
  and modified timestamps (currently I am using triggers)?
- How can I enforce foreign key constraints.
- Should I be using Varchar(255) in SQL Server? (Maybe Text, Varchar(MAX) is better)

I am using Visual Studio 2010 to create the tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you can probably use PHPMyAdmin (or something similar) to script out the table creation process to SQL Server. You can take a look at what is automatically created for you to get an idea of what you should be using. After that, you should take a look at SSMS (SQL Server Management Studio) over Visual Studio 2010. Tweaking the tables that your script will create will be easier in SSMS - in fact, most database development tasks will be easier in SSMS.

**What data type should I use to the primary key column (uniqueidentifier, bigint, int)?**
Depending on how many records you plan to have in your table, use int, or bigint. There are problems with uniqueidentfiers that you will probably want to avoid. [INT vs Unique-Identifier for ID field in database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1151625/int-vs-unique-identifier-for-id-field-in-database)

**What should I use for the timestamps (timestamp, datatime, datetime2(7))?**
timestamps are different in SQL Server than in MySQL. Despite the name, a timestamp is an incrementing number that is used as a mechanism to version rows. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182776%28v=sql.90%29.aspx . In short though, datetime is probably your best bet for compatibility purposes.

**How should I enforce the created and modified timestamps (currently I am using triggers)?**
See above. Also, the SQL Server version of a "Timestamp" is automatically updated by the DBMS. If you need a timestamp similar to your MySQL version, you can use a trigger to do that (but that is generally frowned upon...kind of dogmatic really).

**How can I enforce foreign key constraints.**
You should treat them as you would using innoDB. See this article for examples of creating foreign key constraints http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/09/08/sql-server-%E2%80%93-2008-creating-primary-key-foreign-key-and-default-constraint/

**Should I be using Varchar(255) in SQL Server? (Maybe Text, Varchar(MAX) is better)**
That depends on the data you plan to store in the field. Varchar max is equivalent to varchar(8000) and if you don't need varchar(255), you can always set it to a lower value like varchar(50). Using a field size that is too large has performance implications. One thing to note is that if you plan to support unicode (multilingual) data in your field, use nvarchar or nchar.